# Not able to refresh the jface table viewer

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have built a table viewer, and i have set the following methods on it:

```
viewer.setContentProvider(new SampleContentProvider());
viewer.setLabelProvider(new SampleLabelProvider());
viewer.setInput(object);
```

SampleContentProvider implements IStructeredContentProvider

and

SampleLabelProvider implements ILabelProvider

I get the following exception when the viewer is refreshed after modify action on a table item:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:

            at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)

            at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:73)

            at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.disassociate(StructuredViewer.java:640)

            at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:727)

            at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:649)

            at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:636)

            at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$7.run(StructuredViewer.java:1487)

            at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1422)

            at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1383)

            at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1485)

            at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.refresh(ColumnViewer.java:537)

            at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1444)
```

I have debugged SampleContentProvider's getElements , it is returning an array of objects ...

I have no clue why this refresh call on the viewer occassionally causes this exception and therefore not updating the table with modified content.

Comment: How are you modifying the table? You must **not** change the `TableItem` directly.

Comment: Each table item is a model object for me. So whenever i click a table item and click on modify button , a new dialog pops up, there i modify some properties on the object and save the object. Finally i do a viewer.refresh();

Comment: Well the error is because `TableItem.getData()` is returning null, are you calling `TableItem.setData` at all?

Comment: i have used a sorting technique for sorting columns, there im calling TableItem.setText()

Comment: As I said you must not use `TableItem` directly, `TableViewer` handles them and altering them leads to failures like this. To sort use `TableViewer.setComparator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure is caused by `TableItem.getData()` returning `null` which is not allowed.

When you use `TableViewer` to manage a table you must not manipulate the `TableItem` objects directly, `TableViewer` is in charge of these and changing them will lead to failures.

To sort a table use the `TableViewer.setComparator` call to supply a class based on `ViewerComparator` which sorts the objects in your data model.